# Was silent reading or reading aloud the norm in pre-modern (esp. Tang through Ming eras) China?

Tags: china, language, education, ming-dynasty

Many scholars argue that in ancient Greco-Roman culture, reading aloud was the norm, as seen in examples like Augustine's *Confessions*, where Augustine sees someone reading silently and sees this as highly unusual. Paul Saenger's *Space Between Words* argues that the shift to silent reading in Europe was closely tied to word spacing in medieval manuscripts*, and I think Ivan Illych argues something similar in *In the Vineyard of the Text.* (Of course, some other scholars dispute these theories.)

I've recently read Wu Cheng'En's *Journey to the West* (Ming Dynasty) and some Tang-dynasty poetry (Li Bai) from China, and I was wondering if there was a similar shift from reading aloud to reading silently in pre-modern Chinese culture, moving from ancient texts like the *Book of Songs* to the Classic Novels. So: what were common reading practices in ancient China, and was there a likely shift from reading aloud to reading silently? (If this should be directed to a different exchange, my apologies!)

*Edited to add citations: Paul Saenger, *[Space Between Words](https://books.google.com/books?id=w3vZaFoaa3EC&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, 1997:  [see especially the intro and final chapter; the intro also makes the point that Chinese as a character-based language is much easier to learn silently than, say, Latin]. For the opposing view (thanks CMW!), which seems to be the scholarly consensus at this point, see A. K. Gavrilov, "[Techniques in Classical Reading](https://www.jstor.org/stable/639597),"
*The Classical Quarterly*, Vol. 47, No. 1 (1997), pp. 56-73, .

Comment: That the Greeks and Romans didn't read silently [has been thoroughly debunked](http://kiwihellenist.blogspot.com/2016/02/reading-silently-and-reading-out-loud.html).

Comment: I have no data that bears directly on the question, but I'll note that reading aloud helps sound out words. This would have been helpful with Latin or Greek; less so with Chinese.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I've been aware that there was some controversy over the assertion that ancient Greek and Romans didn't read aloud, but I wasn't sure of the current scholarly consensus on the issue; CMW's article provided in the link is a *very* helpful overview. And thanks, Mark Olson, for the point about phonetic vs. character-based languages! I am still wondering which was the *norm* in pre-modern Chinese literary culture (i.e., were novels read aloud socially, as they sometimes were in Europe through the Victorian era?). But this gives me something to go on for now...